# Remote Desktop over Internet

Tags: windows, remote-desktop

I want to use remote desktop outside my LAN.
To do this, I configured my router to do port forwarding (as you can see in the image below):

[image]

When I opened the remote desktop over the second computer, and typed my external IP address, my remote desktop didn't work (it showed me the typical message that the computer I want to connect to is maybe shut down, etc.)

- I checked my firewall, and all the remote desktop settings and they are all OK.

So, what do you think may be the reason?
My IP remains the same even though I’m using DHCP. Could this one be the reason?

Comment: Checkpoints: Is your computer configured to allow remote access connections? Have you nmap'd your external IP to verify port 3389 is open?

Comment: What do you mean nmapd?
I can see when i do netstat the the port is open..
Like i said, i allowed the remote access settings..

Comment: then you need to nmap. Best way to isolate.

Comment: I edited my comment..
Also, i now see in the NMAP too that RDP is listening in that port

Comment: Someone can help?

Comment: RDP works over both TCP and UDP. Make sure those both are routed to your machine. Next, you can try to telnet from the client to the IP:3389 and make sure that a connection can be established (maybe your router gets a dynamic IP).

Comment: So you say if i'll make it static it will work?